# How to get last message between current user and others?

Tags: python, sql, django, postgresql, python-2.7

I have a **Message** django-model, with fields:

- id (Primary Key)
- user_sender(Foreign Key to User instance)
- user_receiver(Foreign Key to User instance)
- send_date (DateTime)
- message (Char)
- status(Boolean)

So, i'm trying to get all last messages between my current user and other users.

> Examples:
>
> If i have 3 users:
>
> John send message to Sarah(17.08.2015) (id=1)
>
> Sarah send message to John(20.08.2015) (id=2)
>
> John send message to Max (18.08.2015) (id=3)

I need to get only messages with ID 2 and 3.

I'm trying this query, but getting all 3 messages:

```
Message.objects.filter(
            Q(user_sender_id=1) |
            Q(user_receiver_id=1)).\
order_by('user_sender', 'user_receiver', '-send_date').\
distinct('user_sender', 'user_receiver')
```

So, what i am doing wrong? Why after using distinct by foreign keys i'm getting 3 messages?

UPD #1:

```
class Message(models.Model):
    """
    Model for user messages.
    - Who
    - Whom
    - When
    - Message
    - Status
    """
    user_sender = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="sender")
    user_receiver = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="receiver")
    send_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    message = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    status = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s %s ->%s' % (self.send_date, self.user_sender, self.user_receiver)
```

Comment: please show the real code for your models

Comment: If you want to get messages 2 and 3 with this query then you are looking for messages to or from John. But message 1 is also from John.

Comment: @Pynchia updated question.

Comment: @Ivan and what? Can you provide solution to discard duplicates pairs Foreign Keys?

Comment: @Ivan is saying your query does not match your requirement. It should be `Message.objects.filter(user_sender_id=1).latest('send_date')`

Comment: @AndreyIlyin NO. Because there are no duplicates there.  There are 3 dictinct pairs (user_sender, user_receiver) in your example data.

Comment: @Pynchia i need latest message in conversation. John can be sender or receiver.

Comment: @ivan John -> Sarah and Sarah -> John - duplicates. Need only one message(latest).

Comment: then how can you expect messages with ID=2 and ID=3 only?

Comment: @Pynchia see in any messenger(telegram, viber etc). If you go to the 'Inbox', you see all conversation preview. Each of them have latest message (you can been sender or reciever in this message, doesn't matter). That's what i need.

Comment: Still, your example result does not match what you require. Try with `message.objects.filter(Q(user_sender_id=1) | Q(user_receiver_id=1)).latest('send_date')`

Comment: @Pynchia this return only 1 message. I need all latest messages between current user(John) and other.

Comment: yes, I know: you are querying for id=1 only

Comment: @Pynchia i querying id=1 only for example.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26640221/how-to-create-a-conversation-inbox-in-django/26641580#26641580 looks like what i need, but need to filter Q like in my query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sent = Message.objects.filter(user_sender_id=1).order_by('-send_date')[:1]
received = Message.objects.filter(user_receiver_id=1).order_by('-send_date')[:1]

from itertools import chain

messages = list(chain(sent, received))
```

Comment: It looks nice, but don't work fully successfull.
I'm test it with my database with messages and it seems always getting only 2 messages? Why it discarding others?

Comment: Because [:1] only will receive one message, for each queryset*. if you want the last five messages received, just change the [:1] to [:5] in the second queryset

Comment: Wow! Than looks great.
Mark as Answer and go sleep, tomorrow will test it. Thank you :)

Comment: It looks like it doesn't work as i need. It select all messages, but i need only one(latest) between current user and other users.

Comment: the queryset sent and received, with the [:1], will bring only one message, can show ur querysets code?

Comment: `sent =Message.objects.filter(user_sender_id=token.user_id).order_by('user_sender', '-send_date').distinct('user_sender')`

`received = Message.objects.filter(user_receiver_id=token.user_id).order_by('user_receiver', '-send_date').distinct('user_receiver')`

`from itertools import chain`

           `q = list(chain(sent, received))`

Comment: add in sent, and receveid the [:1] at the end.

Comment: @AndreyIlyin the problem persist?

Comment: Now it's work, but need more tests. If i have some issues i 'up' this topic.

Answer (score 0):

To get all last messages between current user and other users:

```
def is_latest(qs, message):
    # if contact exist in sent and received
    # take lastmessage contact
    if qs:
        if message.send_date < qs[0].send_date:
            return False
    return True

user = User.objects.get(id = 1)
sent = Message.objects.filter(user_sender=user).order_by('user_receiver','-send_date').distinct('user_receiver') 
received = Message.objects.filter(user_receiver=user).order_by('user_sender','-send_date').distinct('user_sender') 
messages = list(chain(sent, received))
contact_list = []
for message in messages:
    if message.user_sender == user:
        c = message.user_receiver                
        if not is_latest(received.filter(user_sender=c), message): continue
    else:
        c = message.user_sender
        if not is_latest(sent.filter(user_receiver=c), message): continue

    contact_list.append({'id':c.id,'email': c.email,'last_message': message.message})

print(contact_list)
```